# Excess 401k Contribution Found After April 15th but before May 17th

Tags: 401k

Hoping for an answer ASAP.  I just found out I have overcontributed to my 401k for 2020 (2 different employers).  It's after April 15th so Fidelity can no longer withdraw the excess.  However, I haven't filed my taxes yet.  I still have 2 days!  Should I go ahead and add that amount to my wages?  Fidelity said the excess can no longer be withdrawn so should I contribute less to my 401k in 2021 to offset the excess in 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are right: Add the amount to your wages, pay the tax and move on with your life.

> To the extent that a corrective distribution is not made within the
> correction period, the excess deferrals may not be distributed until a
> distribution is otherwise permissible under the terms of the plan...

https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/consequences-to-a-participant-who-makes-excess-deferrals-to-a-401k-plan